# Animate view inside Fragment get clipped when crossing its border

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a view in a fragment. This fragment is within a RelativeLayout.
I want to animate this view also outside the fragment borders. However, the view always get clipped when crossing the border. I have tried by setting "android:clipChildren="false"" to everything, but I can't get it to work.

Is this even possible to do?